# How to use map2 to add column to list of dataframes

Tags: r

I'm trying to use map2 to add a column to each dataframe within a list

Here is my attempt:

```
weather_data <- weather_data %>%
                map2(x, y = c("Place1", "Place2", "Place3", "Place4"), ~ x[["Area"]] = y)
```

The idea of this is to add a column entitled "Area" to each dataframe. So the first dataframe in the list would have a column "Area" with a value of "Place1" and so forth...

Many thanks

Comment: Hello, could you provide some data and also how the final result should look like for a couple of example rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved like so:

BTW: First. The arguments to `purrr::map2` are `.x` and `.y`.

```
list(mtcars, iris, mtcars, iris) %>%
  purrr::map2(.y = c("Place1", "Place2", "Place3", "Place4"), function(x, y) { x[["Area"]] <- y; x })
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also make use of the `~` notation in `map2` along with `mutate` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list(mtcars, iris, mtcars, iris) %>%
    map2(c("Place1", "Place2", "Place3", "Place4"), ~ 
               .x %>%
                   mutate(Area = .y))
```